# Put the inverted quotes around a string using index , python

Tags: python

I have a large number of strings in text file and I want to put inverted quotes around the each string as follows.

The text file contains so many lines such as:

> {created_at : July 07, 2014, article : The Turkish government has
>   drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who
>   took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a
>   separate state in southeastern Turkey.}

And I wanted to insert inverted quote around the date and article content like this...

> {created_at : "July 07, 2014", article : "The Turkish government has
>   drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who
>   took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a
>   separate state in southeastern Turkey"} using index method in python..

But I get the result as `{created_at : "July 07", 2014, article : "The Turkish government has drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a separate state in southeastern Turkey}`.. hence it is placing the quotes in wrong positions.

Here is my code:

```
f = open("textfile.txt", "r")
for item in f:
    first_comma_pos = item.find(",")
    print first_comma_pos
    first_colon_pos = item.find(" : ")
    print first_colon_pos
    second_comma_pos = item.find(",", first_comma_pos)
    second_colon_pos = item.find(" : ", second_comma_pos)
    print second_colon_pos
    item = (item[:first_colon_pos+3] + 
        '"' + item[first_colon_pos+3:second_comma_pos] + '"' +
        item[second_comma_pos:second_colon_pos+3] +
        '"' + item[second_colon_pos+3:-1] + '"\n')
    print item
    saveFile= open("result.txt", "a")
    saveFile.write(item)
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
```

Comment: ... and the question is... ?

Comment: Two issues with your question: 1) you don't state what the problem is, and 2) this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.

Comment: updated the question, i dont get any errors , but my code places the inverted quotes in wrong positions as indicated in the question.

Comment: I think you are getting confused about strings vs repr ... or maybe not

Comment: *using index method in python* are you restricted to that or open to other answers?

Comment: @BhargavRao : as I have started with it, want to proceed with the same

Comment: This cannot be parsed correctly unless you state some rules about the use of commas as delimiters. Presumably the substring "July 07, 2014, article" is to be split at some point into a value and a key, but how do we know which comma to split on?

Comment: @JonKiparsky Im pretty sure you just have to make some assumtions

Comment: @JoranBeasley  I'm pretty sure that's a bad idea. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite accurate but for 2 flaws:-

- Your [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) used to find the position of the first comma itself as you hadn't added an extra index
- Your ending `"` was outside your `{`. Thus it used to be thrown out of place

Edited code

```
f = open("textfile.txt", "r")
for item in f:
    first_comma_pos = item.find(",")
    print item
    print first_comma_pos
    first_colon_pos = item.find(" : ")
    print first_colon_pos
    second_comma_pos = item.find(",", first_comma_pos+1)  # Note change
    second_colon_pos = item.find(" : ", second_comma_pos)
    print second_colon_pos
    item = (item[:first_colon_pos+3] + 
        '"' + item[first_colon_pos+3:second_comma_pos] + '"' +
        item[second_comma_pos:second_colon_pos+3] +
        '"' + item[second_colon_pos+3:-2] + '"}\n')  # Note change
    print item
    saveFile= open("result.txt", "a")
    saveFile.write(item)
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
```

Output

> {created_at : "July 07, 2014", article : "The Turkish government has drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a separate state in southeastern Turkey."}

Comment: good job helping to correct his script ... probably more educational value in that then my answer (+1)

Answer (score 2):

pretty hacky but

**fix_json.py**

```
import re,json
s = """{created_at : July 07, 2014, article : The Turkish government has drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a separate state in southeastern Turkey.}"""
parts0 = s.split(":")
data = {}
for lhs,rhs in zip(parts0,parts0[1:]):
    #: assume that the word directly preceding the ":" is the key
    #: word defined by regex below
    key = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z_]","",lhs.rsplit(",",1)[-1]) 
    value = rhs.rsplit(",",1)[0]
    data[key] = value

print json.dumps(data)
```

this of coarse leaves the reading/writing of the files to you ... as well as makes some assumptions about your data based on your example

Comment: This solution makes me very sad.

Comment: I dont disagree ... but given the info provided I think this is what the OP is looking for.... really the correct answer is to adjust the other script to output valid data (json or any other serialized data) instead of making up his own serialization routine

Comment: @JonKiparsky Don't feel sad, Here is [something](http://xkcd.com/) to cheer you up!

Comment: @JoranBeasley That's correct - any answer to the question as asked is a bad answer. (but yours is much preferable to the other one...)

Answer (score 2):

If the data is always that format, you can tokenize bit by bit from the right, eg:

```
s = """{created_at : July 07, 2014, article : The Turkish government has drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a separate state in southeastern Turkey.}"""

created_at, a_sep, article_text = s.strip('{}').rpartition('article :')
start, c_sep, created_date = created_at.rpartition('created_at :')
new_string = '{{{} "{}", {} "{}"}}'.format(
    c_sep,
    created_date.strip(' ,'),
    a_sep,
    article_text.strip()
)

# {created_at : "July 07, 2014", article : "The Turkish government has drawn a roadmap for the return of militants of the banned PKK, who took up arms against the Turkish state in order to carve out a separate state in southeastern Turkey."}
```